# stylesheet not importing in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was just going through this tutorial **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7olvEeBM2I&index=3&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqMA4RdhSnnNcaqOVpX7qi5)** and basically the author recommends that the css stylesheet be imported like so:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('custom-style' );
```

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

My header.php of my theme looks like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php  language_attributes(); ?> >
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php  bloginfo('charset');   ?>">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name');  ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">        

        <?php  wp_head(); ?>

    </head>
    <body <?php  body_class(); ?>>



    <header class="site-header">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a><?php bloginfo('name');  ?></h1>
        <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>
    </header>
```

But i am still not seeing the effect of my stylesheet , can anybody point me to what exactly am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT::** On further inspection i found out that if i post the contents of header.php in index.php the stylesheet is loading fine , which means that my functions.php files is working fine. So i guess the problem is with my header.php file, I have updated above what my header.php file looks like, so can somebody tell me whats wrong with my header.php file now ?

Thank you.

Comment: if you look in the rendered output that will give you a better indication, the code looks correct but depends on get_header() in your template, no function removing stylesheets etc..

Comment: First you can check view page source(i.e) stylesheet path is coming or not..

Comment: @Samyappa my head in the HTML source(inspect element) when i check is empty , even though i have my header file defined as above .

Comment: Can u show me your site url..

Comment: @Samyappa i am working on it locally !

Comment: you will do one thing in your header directly wrote style sheet url like

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentysixteen-style-css'  href='http://localhost/expwordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />after u will made dynamic.

Comment: @Samyappa check my Edit :) thanks alot

Comment: I'm not getting recent update please you can provide your update ;)

Comment: EDIT:: On further inspection i found out that if i post the contents of header.php in index.php the stylesheet is loading fine , which means that my functions.php files is working fine. So i guess the problem is with my header.php file, I have updated above what my header.php file looks like, so can somebody tell me whats wrong with my header.php file now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107965/discussion-between-samyappa-and-alexander-solonik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i was't importing the header like so:

```
get_header();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Comment: where are you adding it? It should be in functions.php file also it needs to be registered

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory() . '/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-style' );
    }
```

The style.css is in your root folder of the theme, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_register_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style' );
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: The stylesheet needs to be registered first before enqueue also there is an answer below mine similar. They need to check if they are using a child theme or if there is more than one header file.